# How to get the Title of ActionBar in non-activity class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   //referenceOfActivity 
  // here is the context, don't know how to use it to get ActionBar title
  Toast.makeText(referenceOfActivity,"Already Liked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want to get the title of action bar within an adapter class. As you can see I have the Context of Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your activity name to your context.
Example;

```
((MainActivity) referenceOfActivity).getSupportActionBar().getTitle()
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot. It Worked.